# how to inject depencies to constructor controller

Tags: api, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

I'm trying to configure an API which a controller use depency injection to inject an object to this controller

```java
public class BaseAPIController
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;
    public BaseAPIController(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // some common functions and properties are declared here
}
public class AccountController : BaseAPIController
{
    public AccountController(Repository repository) : base(repository)
    {  }
}
```

but it throws an exception that tells "Some services are not able to be constructed..."

I tried a solution that use `ILogger<Repository>` instead of using `Repository` instance then this runs properly

```java
public class AccountController : BaseAPIController
{
    public AccountController(ILogger<Repository> repository) : base(repository)
    {  }
}
```

the registion service in startup.cs code

```java
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastController, WeatherForecastController>();
}
```

and the declaration of Repository class

```java
public interface IRepository
{
    void DoSomething1();
    void DoSomething2();
    void DoSomething3();        
}
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public void DoSomething1() {}
    public void DoSomething2() {}
    public void DoSomething3() {}
}
```

How can I archive the configuration above without using ILogger instance
Thanks

Comment: What does the BaseAPIController class look like? You don't have to use ILogger unless the service requires it.

Comment: ah sorry, I missed the inheritance of BaseAPIController. I edited the post
it container some declaration of common functions and properties that can be used in all controllers

Comment: There are still classes missing to diagnose this. Please include all of the relevant code e.g. Repository. Also, please include where you are registering the services e.g. in your Startup.cs file. If it's failing to construct a dependency it's likely to be either you've not registered a dependent service, or its scope is wrong e.g. a Singleton service will require its dependent services to be Singletons too.

Comment: I 've just edited the code above, it's just my new created project based on ASP.net core API template from Visual Studio

Comment: The problem is there's no parameterless constructor for the Repository class so DI cannot create an instance of it. Ideally you'd pass in the connection string using IOptions rather than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the registration you made:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
```

But this is `AccountController`'s constructor:

```
AccountController(Repository repository)
```

Notice how `AccountController` is depending on the concrete type `Repository`; not on the `IRepository` interface. Because of this registration, `Repository` can *only* be resolved through its `IRepository` interface, but not directly (that's by MS.DI's design).

The solution, therefore, is to change `AccountController`'s constructor to the following:

```
AccountController(IRepository repository)
```

Comment: so how can I init the instance of `Repository` object in oder to implement some it in test method. I mean in test method, I have to create instance of controller like this: `var controller = new AccountController(.....); //where .... is an instance of Repository object with fake connection string in it`. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ming, in a test, you would typically inject a fake version. You can do this by creating a `FakeRepository` class that implements `IRepository` and you can supply it to the controller as follows: `new AccountController(new FakeRepository())`.

Comment: And if you want, you can also inject the real repository in your test, as follows: `new AxcountController(new Repository(..))`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that DI cannot create an instance of `Repository` because there is no parameterless constructor. [Take a look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) at the docs for injecting settings rather than requiring a string in the constructor. Add your connection string to your appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "<connection_string>"        
  }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` register your settings class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings));
    ...
}
```

Then your Repository class constructor would look like this:

```
public Repository(IOptions<PositionOptions> options)
{
    _connectionString = options.Value.ConnectionString;
}
```

You also need to inject the interface `IRepository`, not the concrete class into your controller.

```
public class BaseAPIController
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    public BaseAPIController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // some common functions and properties are declared here
}
```